# Count number of elements in an array

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am creating an application, and it has a function which removes elements from an array inside a document in a MongoDB collection.

I need a way to unset the array's field as soon as the array becomes empty right after a remove operation. I need to do this so that I can differentiate between a document that has a non-empty array, and a document that has an empty array.

For example, right now my `section` collection looks like:

```
db.section.find({})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a0a38ad1c6ef24376477c5"), "sectionid" : "BTE4B", 
 "sectionname" : "BTech 4B", "year" : 4,
 "session" : 2016, "courseid" : "BTE-CS", "password" : "pm8xTE0-",
 "students" : 35, "addedon" : "2016-08-02 19:13:38", "teachers" : [ ] }

 { "_id" : ObjectId("57a0a96bd1c6ef24376477cd"), "sectionid" : "BTE4D",
 "sectionname" : "BTech 4D", "year" : 4, "session" : 2016, "courseid" :
 "BTE-CS", "password" : "sHhKr0Ov", "students" : 41, "addedon" :
 "2016-08-02 19:38:43", "teachers" : [ { "facultyid" : "CS-102",
 "subjectid" : "CS-ALGO" } ] }
```

I had applied a *$pull* operation using *mgo* on the `teachers` array of the first document, but I need a way to `$unset` it when it becomes empty.

Currently, I have managed to create a workaround in Go, but I would like to get away without any workarounds.

I hope I am not missing something very trivial here.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to remove` teachers` array along with `$pull` operation in one query or using two queries?

Comment: I need a way in `mgo` to find out that right after a remove function, the `teachers` array of that particular sectionid (on which the remove operation was carried out) is empty or not. Maybe a function that `mgo` provides with, which I can use to determine the size of the array, and if the size returned is 0, I can call an `$unset` (once again, using mgo). But, if existing, some other more elegant solution is welcome too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using the **[`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)** API to do the **[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)** update operation first, this will return the modified document which you can then access the teachers array for checking. Once you check for array emptiness, you can then issue another update operation that calls the **[`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)** operator on the teachers field if the array key has zero elements.

A canonical example in mongo shell follows:

```
change = db.section.findAndModify({
    query: { "sectionid": "BTE4D", "teachers.facultyid": "CS-102" },
    update: { "$pull": { "teachers": { "facultyid" : "CS-102" } } },
    new: true
});

printjson(change);

if (!change.teachers[0]) {
     db.section.update(
        { "_id": change._id },
        { "$unset": { "teachers": "" } }
    );
}

db.section.find({ "_id": change._id })
```

---

Implementing this with mgo, you would need the **[`Query.Apply`](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.Apply)** method which essentially wraps the **[`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#dbcmd.findAndModify)** MongoDB command

```
change := mgo.Change{
        Update: bson.M{"$pull": bson.M{"teachers": bson.M{"facultyid": "CS-102"}}},
        ReturnNew: true,
}
info, err = col.Find(M{"sectionid": "BTE4D"}).Apply(change, &doc)
fmt.Println(doc.N)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To differentiate empty arrays from non-empty you can use the find command with the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator.

If you choose to remove empty arrays you can issue $pull operator with MongoDB [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) (refer the mgo [documentation](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.Apply) for more details) which can atomically return modified document, check if the array is empty and unset it with another query.